# Slack Dialog for search on external data source

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I have couple of question on slack dialog. I developed a form to complete and submit. One field is using external data source and I am able to see the options in the drop down.

Further to enhance this, I would like to know if we can use a search functionality, like if the user types "abc", it show up on those options matching "abc".

Another question which I have is, in the same form, having multiple fields, can we configure the dialog in such a way that, based on one value the other option set has to query and change.

Please help on this part. Thank you.

Dialog json using currently:

```
    {
        "label": "ProjectName",
        "type": "select",
        "name": "prjname",
        "data_source": "external",
    "min_query_length":3
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

## Concept

### Search function

Every select menu with external source to designed to provide a search function. Once the user enters at least `min_query_length` chars its supposed to automatically start matching against your input. However, the actual matching has to be done by your app. Slack will be sending your app the characters the user entered and your app need to respond with the list of matches. If implemented correctly this will result in a search function.

### Updating elements before submit

The user has to click on "Submit" before his input is registered and send to your app. It is not possible to get the intermediate state of elements or update them before the user submits.

## Example code

Here is an example showing how to supply the data for a dynamic menu with external data. The example is in Python using Flask and the standard Slackclient.

This example will show a dynamic select element "City". Once the user enters text in the search field the list of cities is dynamically filtered based on the user input. e.g. "Li" will only show "London" and "Lisabon".

```py
import os
import slack
from flask import Flask, json, request

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/slash', methods=['POST'])
def dialog_show():        
    """shows the dialog"""
    # define dialog
    dialog = {
        "callback_id": "ryde-46e2b0",
        "title": "Request a Ride",
        "submit_label": "Request",
        "notify_on_cancel": True,
        "state": "Limo",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Pickup Location",
                "name": "loc_origin"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Dropoff Location",
                "name": "loc_destination"
            },
            {
                "label": "City",
                "name": "city",
                "type": "select",
                "data_source": "external"
            }
        ]
    }

    # open the dialog
    client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])
    response = client.dialog_open(
        trigger_id=request.form.get('trigger_id'),
        dialog=json.dumps(dialog)
    )    
    assert response["ok"]

    return ""

@app.route('/interactive', methods=['POST'])
def dialog_submit():
    """handle dialog submission"""
    payload_json = request.form["payload"]    
    payload = json.loads(payload_json)
    print(payload)
    return ""

@app.route('/options_load', methods=['POST'])
def dialog_options_load():    
    """provide filtered list of options based on input for dialog"""
    payload_json = request.form["payload"]    
    payload = json.loads(payload_json)    

    # example list of all options
    cities = {
        "Berlin": 1,
        "Copenhagen": 2,        
        "Lisabon": 3,
        "London": 4,
        "Madrid": 5,
        "Oslo": 6,
        "Paris": 7,
        "Rom": 8,
        "Stockholm": 9
    }

    # find matching options
    # will match if user input string is in name
    options = list()
    for name, value in cities.items():
        if payload["value"] in name:
            options.append({
                "label": name,
                "value": value
            })

    # build response structure
    response = {
        "options": options
    }

    return json.jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000) #run app in debug mode on port 8000
```

Comment: Thank you very much Erik for your response, But the default search option is not matching the characters. Rather showing up the whole list. 

Could you share some sample json field code apart from the common user document way. 

All I am stuck is at this stage, where I have configure the field in the dialog and its not matching. Should I have handle the same from the app, like take the typed characters and query back and show up the results.

Something like that.

Comment: On second thought I think I misrepresented how it works. Slack is not doing the actual matching, just sending your app the characters the user entered. The matching has to be done by your app. I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh yes Eric, Do you have any sources to look in to to fix this search issues. My app is able to capture the characters entered, but not sure how to handle the same with the search. If you got any sample python code, that would be really helpful for me.